# For a nested 2D array, how could I get an array of the final column? Split on column?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I have a 2D array:

```py
dataset = [[2.7810836,2.550537003,0],
        [1.465489372,2.362125076,0],
        [3.396561688,4.400293529,0],
        [1.38807019,1.850220317,0],
        [3.06407232,3.005305973,0],
        [7.627531214,2.759262235,1],
        [5.332441248,2.088626775,1],
        [6.922596716,1.77106367,1],
        [8.675418651,-0.242068655,1],
        [7.673756466,3.508563011,1]]
```

I wish to create an array which contains elements of the final column from the above array:

```py
arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Ideally something would slice off the final column so I'm left with an `10x1` array and a `10x2` array. I don't necessarily need to keep the column once I've "extracted" it.

I'm not averse to using Pandas but is there a way using Python standard libraries? A nice one-liner? It would need to be generalized and the size of `dataset` can't be assumed, other than it will have more than one column.

Comment: _I'm not averse to using Pandas_ How about NumPy? If you're dealing with numerical arrays, that's probably what you should be using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr = [el[-1] for el in dataset]`